# BVP rooting method

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

How can I get the value of u'[-1], how can I know the StartingInitialConditions it used, why the output is just one solution

```
sola = NDSolve[{u''[t] - 15*(u[t]^2 - t^2)*u'[t] == 0, u[-1] == 0.96, 
u[0] == 0.01}, u, {t, -1, 0}, 
Method -> {"Shooting", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton"}}];

Plot[{u[t]} /. sola // Evaluate, {t, -1, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  How about `u'[-1]/.sola`

Comment: From the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#659822336), "The shooting method by default starts with zero initial conditions so that if there is a zero solution, it will be returned."  This documentation is not necessarily easy to find.

Comment: The documentation I cited earlier not withstanding, the initial condition used by `NDSolve` for `u'[-1]` actually is `-1`.  I obtained it from the method used in [question 119004](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119004/1063).